# Multiple columns error in Oracle Merge statement

Tags: oracle, merge

I'm trying to do an Upsert in oracle by way of a Merge statement.
Now the table that I'm trying to merge into has a composed primary,
so I creat4ed my query like so:

```
MERGE INTO CONTINGENT_COMMISSION CC USING
    (SELECT 
        'ad_adavila' CC_PROD_USERID,
        to_number('42.22', '999,999,999.99') CC_COMM_PERCENT,
        to_number('217,904.08', '999,999,999.99') CC_PREMIUM,
        '2' CC_TRIMESTER,
        '2013' CC_YEAR
     FROM DUAL) SRC
    ON (CC.CC_PROD_USERID || CC.CC_TRIMESTER || CC.CC_YEAR = SRC.CC_PROD_USERID || SRC.CC_TRIMESTER || SRC.CC_YEAR) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
      SET CC.CC_COMM_PERCENT = to_number('42.22', '999,999,999.99'),
          CC.CC_PREMIUM = to_number('217,904.08', '999,999,999.99'),
          CC.CC_TRIMESTER = '2',
          CC.CC_YEAR = '2013'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN      
    INSERT 
        (CC_PROD_USERID,CC_COMM_PERCENT,CC_PREMIUM,CC_TRIMESTER,CC_YEAR)
      VALUES
        ('ad_adavila',to_number('42.22', '999,999,999.99'),to_number('217,904.08', '999,999,999.99'),'2','2013');
```

Now I'm getting the following error whenever I try to run this query.

ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "CC"."CC_TRIMESTER"

Aparently this is caused because the ON clause has more that one column; which is a must in my case because of the composed primary key:

```
CONSTRAINT "CONTINGENT_COMMISSION_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CC_PROD_USERID", "CC_TRIMESTER", "CC_YEAR")
```

Is there anyway to make this work?

Thank you,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "CC"."CC_TRIMESTER"

you can't update column that you use for filter in on clause, just remove this column from update part

```
merge into CONTINGENT_COMMISSION CC
using (select 'ad_adavila' CC_PROD_USERID,
              to_number('42.22', '999,999,999.99') CC_COMM_PERCENT,
              to_number('217,904.08', '999,999,999.99') CC_PREMIUM,
              '2' CC_TRIMESTER,
              '2013' CC_YEAR
         from DUAL) SRC
on (CC.CC_PROD_USERID || CC.CC_TRIMESTER || CC.CC_YEAR = SRC.CC_PROD_USERID || SRC.CC_TRIMESTER || SRC.CC_YEAR)
when matched then
    update
       set CC.CC_COMM_PERCENT = to_number('42.22', '999,999,999.99'),
           CC.CC_PREMIUM      = to_number('217,904.08', '999,999,999.99')
when not matched then
    insert
        (CC_PROD_USERID, CC_COMM_PERCENT, CC_PREMIUM, CC_TRIMESTER, CC_YEAR)
    values
        ('ad_adavila', to_number('42.22', '999,999,999.99'), to_number('217,904.08', '999,999,999.99'), '2', '2013');
```